# Learn to finger march in f by Daniel Turk

Tags: piano, fingering

I am trying to learn to finger 'March in f' by Daniel Turk, but it's driving me nuts how to do it.

It's in  'Essential piano repertoire', selected and edited by  Keith Snell  (preparatory level, page 7). Any tips would be helpful and nice.

[image: exerpt]

Comment: You are going to have to be more specific. What specific problems are you having? Read about [ask] a good question.

Comment: If you have questions about the fingering in a specific part of that piece (e.g. a certain bar), you could upload an image of that sequence. (or maybe write out the which notes to play in each hand)

Comment: but that is a copy write issue though

Comment: as for the problem i have no clue how to finger the piece, i am a beginner in piano etc. thanks for the answers.

Comment: @DarrenSharrocks Regarding the copyright: do not poste the whole piece.  And you have a teacher?

Comment: Well, nobody can help if they can't see the music. But this isn't a copyright issue anyway, since showing a fragment of the music for learning purposes should fall under fair use. You still need to be more specific. "It's driving me nuts how to do it": then you must have tried some things and particular things are not working. What?

Comment: https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=10157276505328332&set=a.241478948331.181278.750728331&type=3 it here Daniel Turk march in f, i do know how to post it on here, best wishes

Comment: no teachers are too expensive

Comment: I see in the image that someone has written finger numbers above the notes. When you try to use those finger numbers to play the piece, what goes wrong? It seems to me that using those fingers should make it fairly easy to play, so you'll have to explain what is going wrong when you use the fingers specified.

Comment: i have no clue what i  am doing so just guessing, and it just confuses me, there i no video i can reference from so i cannot use them.  so its a bit convoluted. i use other people's  views on it as a reference and build from there etc.

Comment: Are you saying you don't know how finger numbers work?

Comment: yes what are correct fingers, do the positions move etc, bit confusing

Answer (score 5):

The little numbers above the notes are meant to indicate which finger to use to play each note. For example, in the image in your question, there is a **3** above the first note, and then hand-written there are the numbers **4**, **3**, **2**, **1** above the notes of the descending part at the end of the first measure.

The fingers of both your right and left hands have the following numbers:

1. Thumb
2. "Index" or "Pointer" finger
3. Middle finger
4. "Ring" finger
5. "Pinky" finger

So that means for the right hand part in the picture, you play the first two notes with your middle finger, then use your ring finger to play the third note, middle for the fourth note, index finger for the fifth note, and thumb for the sixth note (the last note of the measure).

Notice that you don't have to move your hand at all to play the notes with the fingers as written. Usually finger numbers are chosen and written in to allow for the minimum of hand movement, especially for beginner pieces like this one.

Comment: i  added the notes, how ever i d o not know if they are correct, if a more advance piano person can comment  that would be nice etc

Comment: @DarrenSharrocks There is no one "correct" fingering for any piece. You have to figure out which fingering works best for your hands. I would finger the piece in the image exactly as written. I'm very confused because in your comments you indicated you didn't know how finger numbers work, but apparently you do know how they work. So I have no idea what you're actually asking at this point.

Comment: Well put it this way. I know we have ten fingers on our hands, but there is lots of cross overs and position moves in piano playing, and they catch a beginner like me unawares very easily. There is a advance  way of doing this piece, in which the player would know how to plot the correct fingers.  so when i place the fingers on the piano, i have no clue if its correct and if i am not careful i could go in the wrong direction  and mess up. Case in point the one below it 
 is March in G i got the fingering from a video on  u tube. I am not able do this for march in  F so i i am left in a loop

Comment: @DarrenSharrocks The fingering is already written in for March in F in the picture. I thought you said you were the one who wrote in the fingering. When you play those notes using those fingers, what problem do you have?

Comment: In my low experience  of  notations on piano pieces i believe and am sure i am incorrect. so i am asking a more advance person who knows the piano and music notation, am i on the right lines and what would they do for fingering in regards to the piece.

Comment: @DarrenSharrocks Do you think, the answer from Todd Wilcox was helpful to you, or did you know all this already? If it was not helpful, what exactly do you expect in an answer? Btw, it is normal to mix up things in the beginning - play more slowly if that happens.

Comment: @DarrenSharrocks This site is about discussing objective answers to questions, so we can tell you how fingering works and what the finger numbers mean, but we don't discuss our opinions of specific fingerings. I've already said that I would finger the piece in question the same way it is written in the image, so I don't know what more you want in terms of a more advanced person. I've been playing piano for almost 40 years. Only one person can tell you if a specific fingering works right for you, and that's you.

Comment: look i am a beginner so i do not how to finger a piece of music. If you say you play the piano for over 40 years that is would of been obvious, instead of going into the relm of paranoia about what my supposed motives are. i asked the question how does one finger this piece of music, the right answer would of been i do not know what is best for you but i would do it this way  or that, end of  just they do on u tube.

Comment: @DarrenSharrocks Actually my answer is “finger it the way the written finger numbers say to finger it”. I still don’t understand why that’s not an acceptable answer for you. I’m not paranoid, just confused by your comments. Each of them seems to be asking the same question over and over again even though I feel like I’ve already answered it. My real advice is you need a teacher. Some things can’t be learned from the internet. Piano is one of them.